# Django. Complex annotations require an alias. What is alias here?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the maximun & minimum value of a model with this query:

```
max_min_price = MyModel.objects.annotate(Min('price', Max('price')))
```

But I get the error:

> Complex annotations require an alias

I'm not sure what an alias means here and the docs are not clear in my opinion. Any advice will help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to give a name to the result of `Min`, since Django wouldn't be able to derive the name for complex aggregate functions:

```
max_min_price = MyModel.objects.annotate(min_price=Min('price', Max('price')))
```