# Django/Postgres - No function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search, casting

I'm trying to create a search system in my Django and Postgresql project but I keep running into an error when I try to make a query.

Whenever I try these commands in the shell:

```
vector = SearchVector('title','tags')
query = SearchQuery('book') | SearchQuery('harry')

My_Library.objects.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity(vector,test),).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

I get the error:

"No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

I've been testing other options for a while, and the only way I can successfully pass a search query without an error is by using two strings in the place of *query* and *vector*.

```
My_Library.objects.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('title','my search query'),).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

This will successfully pass my search with no error.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

I've been basing my code off of this [Full Text Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TrigramSimilarity` takes 2 `strings` as arguments

You're trying to pass it a `SearchVector` and a `SearchQuery`.
that won't work

If you want to search by multiple tags, you probably need to aggregate multiple of the similarity queries with a `|` and then sort on similarity, something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

My_Library.objects.annotate(
    Q(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('title','my search query'),)) |
     Q(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('title','my search query'),))
    ).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
```

More details on Q
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects

Comment: When I try this I get "Q is not defined." Where'd you get that from?

Comment: from django.db.models import Q

Comment: Okay now that I have import Q I get another error: TypeError: Complex annotations require an alias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375339/django-complex-annotations-require-an-alias-what-is-alias-here